# Как правильно изменить массив в файле?

Tags: php

Парсю таблицу эксель по библиотеке PHPExcel и хочу заменить массив в файле на новый который в таблице, в таблице у меня такой массив `[1, 2, 3]` ну ы смысле, я его так сделал

```
$arr = array_merge(...parse_excel_file($_FILES['input_file']['tmp_name'])); 
 
$import = "<?php\n\n" . '$ids = ' . var_export($arr, true); 
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/php/ids.php', $import);

function parse_excel_file($filename){ 
 $result = array(); 
 // получаем тип файла (xls, xlsx), чтобы правильно его обработать 
 $file_type = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify( $filename ); 
 // создаем объект для чтения 
 $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader( $file_type ); 
 $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load( $filename ); // загружаем данные файла 
 $result = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(); // выгружаем данные 
 
 return $result; 
}
```

Но в файл почему-то заносится вот такой код

```
<?php

$ids = array(
   0 => 1.0,
   1 => 2.0,
   3 => 3.0
)
```

а должно быть вот так

```
<?php

$ids = array(
   1,
   2, 
   3
);
```

Что не так? Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: а что делает parse_excel_file ?

Comment: получает данные из таблицы excel виде массива

Comment: Он мне возвращает все нормально, он заносит почему-то неправильно

Comment: обновил, гляньте

Comment: var_export говорит, что в массиве float

Comment: а как это исправить и чтобы он не добавлял ключи?

Comment: ключи это норм, просто вы их не показываете во втором случае, они все равно неявно есть. $a = [1,2,3]; var_export($a); - будет с последовательными индексами от 0

Comment: про флоат - я с phpexcel не работал, но вероятно, он читает так из экселя. Преобразуйте в int

Comment: а как преобразовать? Покажите пожалуйста на моем примере

Comment: https://onlinephp.io/c/b7ed6

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: но в этом не очень много смысла, если вы явно не проверяете на int. для php 2.0 и 2 - одно и тоже в подавляющем большинстве случаев

Comment: у меня просто в таблице находятся айди юзеров, а 1.0 таких же нет ;)

Comment: ну,  тогда да :)